# Is blacksmithing through Allomancy possible?

Tags: magical-theory, mistborn, cosmere

My real question can be broken down into these two parts:

**Is it possible for Lurchers and Coinshots to push/pull specific parts of one metal object?  Or, to make it easier, two metal objects welded (or something) together?**

**If so, is it possible and/or practical to use Lurcher/Coinshot teams for blacksmithing if a forge isn't available?**

Comment: Marsh managed to stretch a gun so hard it broke in two pieces, but used duralumin, and had a lot of practice.

Answer (score 4):

It is *possible* to Push or Pull on specific parts of a metal object, yes.

> Kelsier grabbed the bars, flaring both steel and iron, Pushing
> against one tip of each bar and Pulling against the opposite tip.

- Mistborn: The Final Empire, Chapter 34 [Kelsier's fight with the Inquisitor]

However, Kelsier is unusually skilled with Iron and Steel.

> "*This* is his specialty - Pushing and Pulling with expert control."

-same chapter [Vin thinking about Kelsier]

Also, from a 2008 interview with Brandon Sanderson:

> sporkify (18 October 2008)
> How much control do Allomancers have over pushing and pulling metals?
>
> Brandon Sanderson (20 October 2008)
> Depends on the Allomancer. Zane and Kelsier were both unusually skilled in this area, and represent the higher end of what is possible.

Comment: Nice! I guess the rules are a little different from Forging, then.

Comment: It is also likely that the principles mentioned by Mat *do* matter, but that (as with, for example, Pushing and Pulling metal inside someone’s body) they aren’t absolute.

Comment: Actually, I doubt they apply for this power. Forgery is the most Spiritual Realm heavy Cosmere magic we've seen; Iron and Steel are Physical Allomancy. EDIT: Inquisitors can see blue lines to individual bits of metal in a human's body, and we know a human is Cognitively (and presumably Spiritually) one thing. (And it's not Inquisitor specific; in theory this power can be learned by any Coinshot/Lurcher/Mistborn according to the annotations.)

Answer (score 3):

Kind of. According to a passage in *Emperor’s Soul* which describes forging, the object will eventually consider itself one part, so that means it would be impossible to separate.

> “Here is the point. The longer an object exists as a whole, and the
> longer it is seen in that state, the stronger its sense of complete
> identity becomes. That table is made up of various pieces of wood
> fitted together, but do we think of it that way? No. We see the whole.
>
> “To Forge the table, I must understand it as a whole. The same goes
> for a wall. That wall has existed long enough to view itself as a
> single entity. I could, perhaps, have attacked each block
> separately—they might still be distinct enough—but doing so would be
> difficult, as the wall wants to act as a whole.”
>
> <sub>*The Emperor’s Soul*</sub>

if a Push or Pull acts on the center of mass of an object, and the object considers itself a whole, you might have difficulty pushing and pulling on separate portions in order to shape the object precisely. (It may not be explicitly said where a push or pull acts, but the behavior is consistent with a COM force. (suggested by @Adamant)

Comment: This is quite true. Would you mind if I added the quote that illustrates this?

Comment: @Adamant ninja'd!

Comment: @CHEESE - Are you adding the quote, then?

Comment: @Adamant Oh, no, I was just going to ask young Mat to add it.  Go ahead

Comment: I added the passage that you mentioned. Feel free to roll back the edit if it goes too far.

Comment: Anyway, despite different kinds of magic obtaining on different planets, there are overarching magical principles for the Cosmere (and Brandon is known for being consistent), so something like this is very likely true of Pushing and Pulling.

Comment: Totally covers pushing things together; what about shaping them?

Comment: Im sure you could bend them by putting enough pressure on a certain spot, but it would be impossible if not completely impractical to make weapons and tools like that.

Comment: @CHEESE - Well, if a Push or Pull acts on the center of mass of an object, and the object considers itself a whole, you might have difficulty pushing and pulling on separate portions in order to shape the object precisely. (It may not be explicitly said where a push or pull acts, but the behavior is consistent with a COM force).

Comment: @MatrimCauthon Put that in the answer!

Comment: There are also later examples in the *Wax and Wayne* series of an allomancer pushing on distinct parts within a whole, but only on objects that have distinguishable mechanical parts.

Comment: i feel like using emperors soul to answer this is slightly offpoint

Comment: not when you consider that they are all Comer novels and ruled by the same rules

Comment: *cosmere novels